# Radiowaves and electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, resource-recommendations, radio-frequency

I have a simple question: What part of physics study radiowaves and electromagnetic waves? Can you link a source where can I find basics of radiowaves pdf or something?

Comment: How basic? Lots of basic educational material from ham radio websites (even an amateur radio SE at ham.stackexchange), for example. Or basic Electricity and Magnetism texts.

Comment: Are you looking for the term *Electromagnetics*?

Comment: try Haslett: Essentials of Radio Wave Propagation, ISBN-13 978-0-511-37112-7 or Seybold: Introduction to RF Propagation, ISBN-13 978-0-471-65596-1

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks, I will try

Comment: these are general books on RF propagation but if you can also be more specific what is that you  do not understand or looking for I might be able to suggest something more concrete on the subject.

Comment: @hyportnex I was refering to radiowaves that are used in everyday life such as FM/AM radio, tv remote controllers, garage opener remo keys, auromobile remote key, etc. I was looking for a good e-book about this subject, but couldn't find one that I need. I'm a programmer so I want to gain knowledge about those radiowaves in the scope of programming.

Comment: start here http://homes.ieu.edu.tr/hozcan/CE360/ especially this http://homes.ieu.edu.tr/hozcan/CE360/Lect6-7-RadioTheory.pdf

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks a lot, I will definitely look into that

Answer (score 1):

Talking about radio waves, it depends on how you are studying the radio waves, for example, if you are talking about radio waves on an astronomical scale, there is a subfield of astronomy known as [radio astronomy](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/definition/radio-astronomy#:%7E:text=Definition%3A%20Radio%20astronomy%20is%20a,back%20from%20the%20extragalactic%20nebula.). Similarly, electromagnetic waves are not individually studied as a separate field. They are also applied in several fields such as astronomy and astrophysics, optics, etc.

Comment: I was refering to radiowaves that are used in everyday life such as FM/AM radio, tv remote controllers, garage opener remo keys, auromobile remote key, etc. I was looking for a good e-book about this subject, but couldn't find one that I need. I'm a programmer so I want to gain knowledge about those radiowaves in the scope of programming.